# Why is class not in classpath inside gmaven-plugin script?

Tags: java, maven-2, groovy, hsqldb, gmaven-plugin

This is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <classpath>
                <element>
                  <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
                  <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                  <version>1.8.0.10</version>
                </element>
              </classpath>
              <source>
                Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver")
              </source>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Output:

```
$ mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
...
[INFO] --- gmaven-plugin:1.3:execute (default) @ foo ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.866s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun May 08 17:53:13 PDT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/1531M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.3:execute 
(default) on project foo: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver -> [Help 1]
...
```

Why this class in not in classpath?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this post](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Gmaven-console-Groovy-Sql-classloading-td370598.html) I found out how to solve the problem:

```
import org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
def driver = new jdbcDriver()
```

I can't understand why it doesn't work through class loader...